# How to remove <p> tag in xmlpullparser

Tags: java, android

i made an rss reader which displays the rss feed text on the device itself. Now i have one problem left. The text always shows tags like `<p>` and so on. How can I remove them?
Here is all of my code!

```
package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ((TextView) (findViewById(R.id.Text))).setText(intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
    }

}

package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            addRssFragment();
        }
    }

    private void addRssFragment() {
        android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("fragment_added", true);
    }
}

package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<RssItem> items;
    private final Context context;

    public RssAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle;
    }
}

package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class RssFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            startService();
        } else {
            // If we are returning from a configuration change:
            // "view" is still attached to the previous view hierarchy
            // so we need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssService.class);
        intent.putExtra(RssService.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Once the {@link RssService} finishes its task, the result is sent to this ResultReceiver.
     */
    private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            List<RssItem> items = (List<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssService.ITEMS);
            if (items != null) {
                RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occured while downloading the rss feed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        };
    };

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
        String test = item.getDescription();
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("test",(item.getDescription()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

public class RssItem {

    private final String title;
    private final String description;

    public RssItem(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

`package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;


import android.util.Xml;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RssParser {

    // We don't use namespaces
    private final String ns = null;

    public List<RssItem> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
        String title = null;
        String description = null;
        List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                description = readDescription(parser);
            }
            if (title != null && description != null) {
                RssItem item = new RssItem(title, description);
                items.add(item);
                title = null;
                description = null;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    private String readDescription(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
        String description = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
        return description;
    }

    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }

    // For the tags title and description, extract their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

package com.example.MPAK.mynewsappfragment;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class RssService extends IntentService {

    private static final String RSS_LINK = "http://www.pcworld.com/index.rss";
    public static final String ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

    public RssService() {
        super("RssService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service started");
        List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
        try {
            RssParser parser = new RssParser();
            rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
        receiver.send(0, bundle);
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(String link) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Exception while retrieving the input stream", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas?

In generel it opens a xml file. reads the topic,saves it in a list.
If i click on the topic it opens a new activity displaying the text. An example for the text is:

```
<p> Weell,well,well what have we here: no less then three independent&nsbsp;confirmations that <a=href="http ...................... and so on.
So it just reads the whole text but ignres the html tags or lets say it displays them instead of using them.
```

Comment: could you give us any input/output result?

Comment: use Html.fromHtml("your <p> text"); example :--

myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use [Html::escapeHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.CharSequence)) to first escape html tags and the continue processing your data.

Comment: do you mean here?:
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                description = readDescription(parser);
            }

Comment: you probably want `Html.fromHtml`. escapeHtml takes a plain text input and returns a valid HTML string (escaped entities such as `&lt;` for `<`).